# how to run a single transaction in Authorize.net and payout to multiple accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorize.net

I am working on an e-commerce application where we want to charge the user for a product and when he pays for it, send the payment amount to 2 different accounts. Is this possible?

One way is to run 2 separate transactions, but is there a way to do it in single transaction to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to run two seperate transactions only, because you will have only one login key for your current session. Authorize.net's current API doesnt allow any such facility of forwarding payment to some other account etc.